# Umbraco TinyMCE Editor in Custom Page

Tags: tinymce, umbraco, umbraco7

I have website , developed using Umbraco CMS, SQL server and asp.net C#, and I have created custom modules to the website using asp.net,and I want to use  Umbraco TinyMCE Editor in Custom Page, instead the .Net textbox , please if any body know send me or tell me about some URL help me to do that

Comment: In the public part of the website or in the backoffice?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added an example of what you have tried so far

Comment: in the back-end of the website.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this blog post [Umbraco 7: Use the rich text editor (TinyMCE) in a custom section](http://www.enkelmedia.se/blogg/2013/12/4/umbraco-7-use-the-rich-text-editor-tinymce-in-a-custom-section.aspx)

It tells you exactly how to reuse rich text editor (TinyMCE) in your custom page

Below are snippet from the blog post option 3:

In your View

```
<umb-property
    property="property"
    ng-repeat="property in properties">
    <umb-editor model="property"></umb-editor>
</umb-property>
```

In your angular Controller

```
$scope.properties = [{
                        label: 'bodyText',
                        description: '',
                        view: 'rte',
                        config: {
                            editor: {}, // empty for now
                            hideLabel: true
                        }, hideLabel: true
                    }];
```